# Process Views outside viewflow.frontend

Tags: django, django-viewflow

I want to integrate processes, starting them etc., outside of the standard `viewflow.frontend`. To do I have been trying to create a simple page where I can start a new process, but have been struggling to find a way to implement it.

One approach was to defined a url to `url('^start_something, CustomStartView.as_view())` with `CustomStartView` subclassing `CreateProcessView` from `viewflow.flow.views.start`. This ended in getting error after error, whenever I fixed one. I am quite sure now that this isn't the right way to do it, also because the `View` is used as a parameter of the `Flow` class itself and probably needs to be used differently than a common view.

What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Viewflow views need to be parametrized by `flow_class` and `flow_task` instance. So you can include a start view as following::

```
url('^start/', CreateProcessView.as_view(), {
     'flow_class': MyFlow,
     'flow_task': MyFlow.start})
```

To add a task view URL config, you need to use `process_pk` and `task_pk` parameters

```
url('^(?P<process_pk>\d+)/approve/(?P<task_pk>\d+)/', ApproveView.as_view(), {
     'flow_class': MyFlow,
     'flow_task': MyFlow.approve
})
```

For each node, you also can enable detail, and various actions URLs, ex:

```
url('^(?P<process_pk>\d+)/approve/(?P<task_pk>\d+)/detail/', DetailTaskView.as_view(), {
     'flow_class': MyFlow,
     'flow_task': MyFlow.approve
}),
url('^(?P<process_pk>\d+)/approve/(?P<task_pk>\d+)/cancel/', CancelTaskView.as_view(), {
     'flow_class': MyFlow,
     'flow_task': MyFlow.approve
}),
```

All of that's a big cumbersome.

### Recommended way

You can just include `Flow.instance.urls` that contains all URLs collected and ready for inclusion into an URL config.

```
url('^myflow', include(MyFlow.instance.urls, namespace='myflow'))
```

And at the last, to enable task list views, you can put URL entries manually, ex

```
url('^myflow/inbox/', TaskListView.as_view(), {
    'flow_class': MyFlow}, name="tasks")
```

or just use as `viewflow.flow.viewset.FlowViewSet` class

```
myflow_urls = FlowViewSet(MyFlow).urls

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^myflow/', include(myflow_urls, namespace='myflow'))
]
```

This is the recommended way to include viewflow URLs into a django URL Config. To customize views used in that URL config, you can subclass the FlowViewSet class and provide views in the nodes definition, ex

```
class MyFlow(Flow):
    start = flow.Start(detail_view_class=MyDetailTaskView)
```

For the sample usage, you can checkout the Viewflow Custom UI cookbook example - https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/custom_ui

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This is exactly what I needed! I had used `{'flow_class': Flow}` before, but didn't know what to pass for `'flow_task`. I guess using generic URLs and namespaces is a bit more handy and what I am using now :)