# How to integrate django-viewflow without the front end?

Tags: django, django-viewflow

There is the library Viewflow that I would like to use. I don't need the front end because I already got mine. I've been following the quickstart but I don't see how I can integrate viewflow, without using the front end because there are a lot of relations to the material app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to include `material`, `material.frontend` and `viewflow.frontend` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

In that сase you need at least to implement you own templates set from [viewflow/flow](https://github.com/viewflow/viewflow/tree/master/viewflow/frontend/templates/viewflow/flow)

And manually include flow urls into URL Config

```
from viewflow.flow.viewset import FlowViewSet
from .flows import MyFlow

myflow_urls = FlowViewSet(MyFlow).urls

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^myflow/', include(myflow_urls, namespace='myflow'))
]
```

More about viewflow URLs handling can be found here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/42341071/46548

For the reference check the viewflow custom UI cookbook sample https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/custom_ui

On the next step you can define your own views, instead of built-in, see the corresponding example https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook/tree/master/custom_views